# XPages - populating multiple fields on typeahead selection

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs, typeahead

This might be a straightforward question but I can't see wood for trees at the moment

Problem: I have a typeahead attached to an edit box that looks up values from a view ([based on Tim Tripcony's code](http://www.timtripcony.com/blog.nsf/d6plinks/ttry-7xd5p9)). When a value is selected, I want other edit boxes on the XPage to be populated with values pulled from the corresponding document.

As an example: A username edit box has a typeahead looking up from the NAB. I select "Joe Bloggs" name from the typeahead list and want the email, phone and location edit boxes to be immediately populated with the values from his NAB entry.

I'm banging my head on the wall over this because I'm sure there's an easy and obvious solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Selecting a value from the typeahead should trigger any onChange event defined for the edit box. You can set the other fields by updating the data source directly from within that event:

```
var selectedName = currentDocument.getValue("contactName");
currentDocument.setValue("emailAddress", getEmail(selectedName));
currentDocument.setValue("phoneNumber", getPhone(selectedName));
currentDocument.setValue("location", getLocation(selectedName));
```

Naturally, the above example assumes those are your field names, and that you have the named functions defined elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks Tim, that's pointing me in the right direction. I had thought that I'd be writing something more like
    getComponent("emailAddress").setValue(getEmail(selectedName));
    ...
rather than update the data source. Is there a reason why I should update the data source rather than the Xpage itself - for reasons of best practice or something?

Comment: There are several reasons this approach is the best practice, but arguably the most important are future-proofing and performance.